# Why does the horizon visually appear curved at high altitudes?

Tags: curvature, earth, geometry

As I understand it, the horizon is essentially a circle, since it would result from the intersection of a cone (yours or a camera's projected view surface) with the spherical Earth.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

While not necessarily a perfect circle because the Earth isn't a perfect sphere, I don't understand why it would ever appear curved because it seems logical that the intersection would always result in a flat circular line drawn around the observer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circles appear curved when viewed from somewhere not in the plane of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a moment that there's no Earth under you, but the Moon remains where it is. You are at a very large altitude above the Moon: about $4\times10^8\,\mathrm m$. What does the border of the Moon look like? It's a circle. If you go "down" (towards the Moon), this circle will grow, eventually exceeding your field of view, but still remaining a circle. After you land on the Moon, you'll still see this circle around you: it's the same what you see on the Earth, but simply don't notice the curvature because you look at the projection of this circle onto you in the center.